# Git: Adding the full tree of files to the master

Tags: git, branch

I have an existing folder that has many files and folders with no source control.

I create a git repository in it's root folder:

```
 git init
```

However, there is no "master"

```
git branch
```

returns nothing.

How do I create the `master` branch and have it set as the initial and only branch in a folder with existing files and folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `master` branch is the default branch that is created automatically after you commit the first files:

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```